# Problem Implementing Socialite Stack exchange

Tags: support, authentication, stackoverflow

I get code and access token but I cannot call API function

My url being generated
`https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/me?site=stackoverflow&access_token=lcynp67rMHfm%28DRLjv7CVQ%29%29&key=6521`

```
 {
  "error_id": 400,
  "error_message": "`key` doesn't match a known application",
  "error_name": "bad_parameter"
}
```

Client Id

6521
This Id identifies your application to the Stack Exchange API. Your application client id is not secret, and may be safely embeded in distributed binaries.

Pass this as client_id in our OAuth 2.0 flow.

Socialite Provider Link
`http://socialiteproviders.github.io/providers/stackexchange/`

Answer (score 1):

You're providing the clientid as key, which is not correct.

If you go to the page where you can manage your application you'll need to copy the key:

[image]

> Key
>
> Pass this as `key` when making requests against the Stack Exchange API to receive a [higher request quota](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle).
>
> This is not considered a secret, and may be safely embed in client side code or distributed binaries.